# how to remove thumbnail and LiteSpeed Optimization column in media library list-view?

Tags: media-library, columns

I've searched on the internet, and found out this code from this [link](https://www.isitwp.com/remove-media-columns/)

```
function remove_upload_columns($defaults) {
  unset($defaults['comments']);
  unset($defaults['author']);
  return $defaults;
}
add_filter('manage_upload_columns', 'remove_upload_columns');
```

I put the code into functions.php child theme.
It worked, now the Media Library doesn't have author column.

Since I want to remove the "Uploaded to" column also, so I add this line to the code above:

```
unset($defaults['uploaded to']);
```

but it didn't work. The "Uploaded to" column in the Media Library still there.
I've tried to change it into `uploaded_to`, `uploaded-to` and `uploaded_to`, no luck.
The same thing with LiteSpeed Optimization column, no luck.

The other thing is I also want to remove the thumbnail under "File" column.
My WordPress version is 5.6.2

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.